# How can I convert one type of generic list to another type of generic list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I’m trying to access a list in the view where the controller looks like this:

```
        var listofcourses = viewModel.Instructors.Where(i => i.InstructorID == id).Single().Courses;
        var newListOfCourses = listofcourses.ToList();

        ViewBag.ListOfCourses = newListOfCourses;
```

Then in my view I’m trying to do this:

```
 List<xxxx.ViewModels.InstructorIndexData>theCourses(List<xxxx.ViewModels.InstructorIndexData>)     ViewBag.ListOfCourses;
foreach(var item in theCourses)

 {
   <div>
          <td>  
                @item.Enrollments.FirstOrDefault().InstructorFullName 

            </td>  
            <td>  
                @item.Enrollments.FirstOrDefault().Student.LastName  
            </td> 


        </div>
     }
```

Then I get the error message is:

Cannot convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<xxxx.Models.Course>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<xxxx.ViewModels.InstructorIndexData>`

How can I convert one type of generic list to another type of generic list?

Comment: What's the relationship between `Models.Course` and `ViewModels.InstructorIndexData`?

Comment: foreach(var item in ViewBag.ListOfCourses) you can try this

Comment: You should try AutoMapper, and send the ViewModel like an object to the view and you save it sending it via the viewBag